# Mismatch between VDI size and actual contents

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vdi

I have an Ubuntu VM with 2 VDIs.
One for the OS and another one for storage.

[image]

The reported size is 2MB and windows explorer also shows 2MB.

However I have at least 126GB of data there.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1       137G  126G  4.1G  97% /media/storage
```

Why is that? Am I at risk of losing data?

Comment: Have you examined the VDI without using the VirtualBox configuration tool?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas as in through windows explorer? Yeah 2MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out what was going on.

After loading the storage vdi I made a snapshot in VirtualBox, that created a {UUID}.div inside the Snapshots folder that was 126GB in size.

Also now that I'm deleting snapshots from VirtualBox I can see that it's mergin the snapshots to the main vdi files.